# Background Image Showing Up Under NavBar

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to set a background image for my websites without having it interfere with my navbar. It seems like the image likes to appear for my navbar. It seems like I am having an issue with my css on my navbar? I am fairly new to HTML/CSS so any help would be appreciated :).

[Image Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqOiT.jpg)

```css
html {
  background: url(background-image.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* TOP-NAV CSS */

.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.43;
  color: #484848;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.top-nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.logo:link {
  position: relative;
  color: #484848;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; /*Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* IE */
}

.logo:visited {
  color: #484848;
}

.logo:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Image Logo */

.logo img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 16px 19px;
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* NAV-SEARCH CSS */

#nav-search-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 490px;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Search Bar Form */

#nav-search-wrapper form input {
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 52px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('search-icon.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 25px;
  background-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <header>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalabe=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
      <div class="top-nav clearfix">
      <a href="" class="logo">
        <img src="" class="logo"/>
      </a>
        <div id="nav-search-wrapper">
          <form method="GET" action="">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="nav-search" placeholder="Search" />
          </form>
        </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Ticket Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at your `.navbar` class. It simply hasn't an background property

Comment: Maybe try putting a `background-color: white` for your `.navbar` class?

Comment: I tried setting the background color to a color but it still has the image overlapping my navbar.

Comment: try background:color:white and z-index:999 in your .navbar class

Comment: Still didn't work. @KaushikAndani

Comment: I fixed the issue, I had to place a bg color for my .top-nav class and not navbar

Answer (score 0):

If you want text field become transparent . and your background image for your websites without having it interfere with that navbar.

Then

Add opacity in your .css file .

Like this

```
#nav-search-wrapper { display: inline-block; width: 490px; height: 100%; opacity: 0.6; filter: alpha(opacity=60); }
```

Comment: I wanted to have my whole navbar with the background color white. The search bar is the right color but the rest of it was overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `background-color: #fff` and `z-index` property on your `.navbar`
and see if it overlap your background.

Check this updated answer. all is working fine here or you better post all of your codes so we can figure it out what is the real problem of it.

```css
    body {
    //    background: url(background-image.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #000; /* just to check if the background applies */
    }
    
    /* TOP-NAV CSS */
    .navbar {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.43;
        color: #484848;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background-color: #fff; /* whole top bar will filled by white color */
    }

    .top-nav {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .logo:link {
        position: relative;
        color: #484848;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        /*Chrome/Opera/Safari */
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        /* Firefox */
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        /* IE */
    }

    .logo:visited {
        color: #484848;
    }

    .logo:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    /* Image Logo */

    .logo img {
        position: relative;
        padding: 16px 19px;
        width: 100px;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    /* NAV-SEARCH CSS */

    #nav-search-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 490px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Search Bar Form */

    #nav-search-wrapper form input {
        padding: 18px 10px 18px 52px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #666;
        font-size: 14px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        background-image: url('search-icon.svg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 25px;
        background-size: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <header>
        <div class="top-nav clearfix">
            <a href="" class="logo">
                <img src="" class="logo" />
            </a>
            <div id="nav-search-wrapper">
                <form method="GET" action="">
                    <input type="text" name="search" id="nav-search" placeholder="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Ticket Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: @archeryninja - i updated my answer. see that i replaced `html` to `body` and also i put the whole body a background of black and white for the whole navigation. i dont see any problem with it unless you updated your post with all your codes.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem. I had to set the top-nav with a background. Thank you though.